# Export Python variable translations not working

Tags: python, odoo, translation, odoo-13, po

I'm developing a custom module in Odoo 13 to generate a personalized XMLS report, and  for this I'm using [Base Report XLSX from OCA](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/13.0/report_xlsx). The issue is that when generating the PO document for the translations, it doesn't recognize the variables that I [explicitly marked to export](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/es/developer/misc/i18n/translations.html#explicit-exports) whit "_()", even though I followed all the indications in the official documentation (I think).

The custom module code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, _
class PayrollBatchReportXLSX(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.company_payroll.payroll_batch_report'
    _inherit = 'report.report_xlsx.abstract'
    def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, lines):
        sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Payroll Batch XLSX Report')
        sheet.write(0, 0, _("ACCOUNT"))
        sheet.write(0, 1, _("DEBIT"))
        sheet.write(0, 2, _("CREDIT"))
        sheet.write(0, 3, _("NAME"))
        line_index = 0
        for line_item in lines.slip_ids.line_ids:
            if line_item.salary_rule_id.category_id.code in ['L10N_HN_NET']:
                sheet.write(line_index+1, 2, line_item.total)
                line_index += 1
        for index, employee in enumerate(lines.slip_ids.employee_id):
            sheet.write(index+1, 3, employee.name.upper())
            if employee.bank_account_id.acc_number:
                sheet.write(index+1, 0, employee.bank_account_id.acc_number)
```

And this is the generated PO file:

```
# Translation of Odoo Server.
# This file contains the translation of the following modules:
#  * company_payroll
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Odoo Server 13.0+e\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2022-05-04 16:17+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2022-05-04 16:17+0000\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: \n"
"Plural-Forms: \n"
#. module: company_payroll
#: model:ir.actions.report,print_report_name:company_payroll.payroll_batch_xlsx_report
msgid "'Payroll batch - %s' % (object.name)"
msgstr "'Nómina en lote - %s' % (object.name)"
#. module: company_payroll
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:company_payroll.field_report_company_payroll_payroll_batch_report__display_name
msgid "Display Name"
msgstr "Mostrar nombre"
#. module: company_payroll
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:company_payroll.field_report_company_payroll_payroll_batch_report__id
msgid "ID"
msgstr ""
#. module: company_payroll
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:company_payroll.field_report_company_payroll_payroll_batch_report____last_update
msgid "Last Modified on"
msgstr "Última modificación en"
#. module: company_payroll
#: model:ir.actions.report,name:company_payroll.payroll_batch_xlsx_report
msgid "Payroll Batch XLSX Report"
msgstr "Reporte de nómina por lote"
#. module: company_payroll
#: model:ir.model,name:company_payroll.model_report_company_payroll_payroll_batch_report
msgid "report.company_payroll.payroll_batch_report"
msgstr ""
```

As you can see, the variables to be translated ("_("ACCOUNT")", "_("DEBIT")", etc.) aren't shown anywhere. I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two months later I finally found the answer, happens that Odoo wasn't pulling translations because the name of my module was separated by hyphens (`-`), and this, for some reason, made Odoo not recognize my fields to translate. Simply replace hyphens dashes with underscores (`_`).

Thanks to the person who answered me in the comments (seems that those were deleted).